# Can IIS SMTP Server overwrite recipients?

Tags: windows, iis, smtp

Is there a way (using IIS 6.0 SMTP server) to overwrite the recipients of an email before sending it?

I mean, if an application tries to send an email like this:

```
FROM: bob@gmail.com
TO: ana@gmail.com
Hi Ana :)
```

I want my SMTP server to replace the receiver with `test@test.com`:

```
FROM: bob@gmail.com
TO: test@test.com
Hi Ana :)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### IIS SMTP Sucks

I could not find if SMTP Server supports it. I suppose it doesn't. It seems it only can be done with Microsoft Exchange (non-free).

#### hMailServer

So I gave up on IIS SMTP Server and installed the [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/). It took about 10 mins to install and configure it.

To achieve what I want I've created a vbScript following the [documentation](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v4.4/?page=feature_scripting). It has a lot of forums with code examples for a lot of things, and also the most basic features can be done directly on the UI.

Here is the script I've created:

```
Sub OnAcceptMessage(oClient, oMessage)

  oMessage.ClearRecipients    
  oMessage.AddRecipient "Fabricio Rissetto <my-email@gmail.com>", "my-email@gmail.com"    

  oMessage.save   
  
  Result.value =0     
End Sub
```